# How to line-break on a userform mouse-over tooltip?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to find a way to put line-breaks on a mouseover tooltip

I'd like to display

> Full - Complete overwrite from external Partial - only overwrites
>   non-blank from external No - inputs data only on blank cells

to

> Full - Complete overwrite from external
>   Partial - only overwrites non-blank from external
>   No - inputs data only on blank cells

is there any way to do this

using Excel 2010 btw

Answer (score 1):

This works in Access VBA - no reason it shouldn't work in Excel VBA: **When entering your control tip text, wherever you want a line break, simply press Shift-Enter.**

Since the field (in Access) in which we enter control tip text only shows one line at a time, you will have to use your up and down arrows to scroll through the text in that one-line-at-a-time field to be sure you have it all entered properly.

Answer (score 0):

Linefeeds/carriage returns in the `ControlTipText` property are simply ignored by excel.  A possible workaround is to have a hidden multiline label (formatted to look like a tooltip) whose visibility is toggled by use of both the associated control's and the userform's `MouseMove` events - i.e. `SomeControl_MouseMove` shows the label and `ParentForm_MouseMove` hides it again (possibly after a delay).  This approach can be a bit hit or miss if the user moves the pointer around very quickly.  Another (better, IMHO) solution would be to have a permanently visible label or textbox object somewhere on your form whose caption/value changes according to whichever control is currently under the mouse pointer, again using `MouseMove` events.

EDIT: If, as I suspect, your tooltip is associated with a combobox/listbox control, you might want to consider having your option descriptions in a second column within the control?

Comment: I already know of the hidden label method but I only have a small userform for selection purposes so there is not enough space to fit it. And yes the tooltip is associated with combobox.

Comment: In the end, I just settled to using WinAPI to display a multiline tooltip. Not very elegant and simple but it works

Comment: Care to share your solution?  I'm not very au fait with windows APIs, having always relied on other folks' code snippets, but the more I see of them the more I know :)

Comment: I adapted the code from here [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/401364-tooltips-listbox.html#post1994964). Code is pretty long and a bit tricky to use. Originally for listbox but a simple find and replace made it ready for combobox.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to keep it easy (no api, very short code) :

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
'If Events Then
    Dim list_index As Long, Zero As Long
    Zero = Me.ListBox1.TopIndex
    list_index = Y \ (8 + 2) + Zero ' ; 8 si the size of Font ; note \ is a integer division
    'Me.label1 = Y          'test label
    'Me.label2 = list_index 'test label
    'Me.label3 = Zero       'test label
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ControlTipText = .List(list_index, 1)
    End With
'End If
End Sub
```